# Passing a vector pointer and looping it to change its value

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, reference, stdvector, assignment-operator

I'm trying to pass a vector to a function, loop over it, and modify the values before sending it back, but I'm having a very hard time with the `pointer` and `reference` to make it work:

I understand that `itr` is a pointer. I'm confused about `resource` on the `for loop`. I believe it to be a `reference`, but I keep getting the error:

`error: no viable overloaded '='resource = resource + value`

```
ACTION test::addto(name player){  
    
  auto itr = player.require_find(wallet.value, USER_NOT_FOUND(wallet));
    
  asset value1 = asset(100, ACTION_SYMBOL);
  asset value2 = asset(100, FOOD_SYMBOL);
    
  changeResourceValue(itr->resources, value1);
  changeResourceValue(itr->resources, value2);
    
  player.modify(itr, _self, [&](auto& p) { 
      p.resources = resources;
  });
}

void changeResourceValue(const vector<asset>* resources, asset value){
   for (auto &resource : *resources){
      if(resource.symbol == value.symbol){
         resource = resource + value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely *not* `C` code.

Comment: *I understand that itr is a pointer* -- No, `itr` is an iterator.  An iterator does not necessarily mean it's a pointer.  It can be used using pointer-like syntax (dereferencing, etc.), but that's all.  Then `resource = resource + value;` -- what is the intent of this line?  It would be a lot better if you posted an [mcve], or at the very least, indicate what the variable types are that are being used.  Right now, all we see is `auto itr`, and that doesn't indicate what the actual types are.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Why pass `const` data if you want to change the data?

Comment: *I'm trying to pass a vector to a function, loop over it, and modify the values before sending it back* -- Then the first thing you should do is write a [simple program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0373b50cec04de97) and work with that until you get the desired results.  Once you get the simple program to work then you use that.  If you can't get the simple program to work, then post that program here and we will take a look at it (thus satisfying the [mcve] requirement).

Comment: `auto` sure is convenient, but without `auto` you probably would have seen the mistake almost immediately: https://godbolt.org/z/Eb94YKbcY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the first parameter of the function  `changeResourceValue` is declared with the qualifier `const`

```
void changeResourceValue(const vector<asset>* resources, asset value){
```

It means that you may not change elements of the vector pointed to by the pointer `resources`.

So you need at least to remove the qualifier `const`.

The second problem is that the operator = is not defined for objects of the type `asset`. Maybe the error message is a consequence that the variable `resource` is a constant reference.

Also you need to check whether the member function `require_find` returns a pointer or an iterator in this record

```
auto itr = player.require_find(wallet.value, USER_NOT_FOUND(wallet));
```

Old C++ versions of `std::vector` defined iterators as pointers. But in new versions of `std::vector` iterators are not pointers.

So maybe the function should be declared like

```
void changeResourceValue( std::vector<asset>::iterator resources, asset value);
```

Comment: If I remove the const I get the `error: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const vector<eosio::asset>' to 'vector<eosio::asset> *' for 1st argument,`
If I add the `::iterator` I get `error:  invalid range expression of type 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<eosio::asset *>'; no viable 'begin' function available`

Comment: Also I try to get the iterator as a pointer like this `vector<asset>*  p = *itr->resources;` but I get the error `error: indirection requires pointer operand ('const vector<eosio::asset>' invalid) vector<asset>*  p = *itr->resources;`

Comment: @Icaro If the vector is constant then the function does not make a sense. You are doing something wrong. You may not change a constant vector.

Comment: @Icaro Check whether the member function require_find is declared with the qualifier const. If so then you need to overload it without the qualifier const.

Comment: that was it! I'm used with Node, where `const` means you cannot change the reference it is pointing to, but you can change the content of it. Let me rewrite this to make it work now, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Icaro `const` applies to what's on its left, unless nothing is there, then it applies to what's on its right. So, it means different things depending on its relative position to tokens. For instance, `const vector *` is a mutable pointer to a `const vector` object. You can't change the `vector`'s content, but you can change the pointer to point at a different `const vector` object. Whereas `vector * const` is a `const` pointer to a mutable `vector` object. You can change the `vector`'s content, but you can't change the pointer. And `const vector * const` means nothing can be changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, `resource` is indeed a reference, but to `const asset` and not `asset` because you have a (pointer to) `const` vector. If you want to change a vector, don’t pretend you don’t, i.e. pass a regular, non-const pointer.

Comment: If I remove the const I get the error: `note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const vector<eosio::asset>' to 'vector<eosio::asset> *' for 1st argument`